# Event Added Through API not visible in Google Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are adding an Event through the Calendar API

```
            Event ev = new Event();
            ev.Summary = "ILINK TEST - IGNORE";
            ev.Start = new EventDateTime();
            ev.Start.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
            ev.End = new EventDateTime();
            ev.End.DateTime = ev.Start.DateTime;
            ev.Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
            EventAttendee ea = new EventAttendee();
            ea.Email = "example@example.com";
            ev.Attendees.Add(ea);
            Event evv = service.Events.Insert(ev, "example@example.com").Execute();
```

When we try and view the Event in the users calendar it is not visible.  However we can retrieve the Event directly by Id

```
            EventsResource.GetRequest gr = new EventsResource.GetRequest(service, "example@example.com", "43ha9dpv15h5oj2jv853g4vljk");
            gr.AlwaysIncludeEmail = true;
            Event evv = gr.Execute();
```

When we remove the attendee entry for the Owner "example@example.com" the Event becomes visible in the Calendar

```
             evv.Attendees.Remove(ea);
```

So what we are seeing is that when the Owner of the Event is an attendee then it is not visible in Their Google Calendar.

I have checked the ACL Rules and the following entry exists

```
    ETag    "\"00000000000000000000\""  
    Id      "user:example.example.com"  
    Kind    "calendar#aclRule"  
    Role    "owner"
```

Comment: I tried this on the API Explorer of the developer site, seems to be working fine. Did you check the calendar of the `example@example.com`? Is its Calendar visible in the "My Calendar" section?

Comment: Hi @adjuremods yes all appears normal.  When the Event is generated without adding the user 'example@example.com' as a guest/attendee it is visible...  It has something to do with their being an attendee on the event.  This is why I suspect it may have something to do with ACL Rules?

Comment: Is it possible that the attendee has set in their settings to not show calendar invitations? The setting is called "Automatically add invitations to my calendar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @luc,

The issue here is that the user does indeed have in their Calendar settings the following setting = **'No, only show invitations to which I have responded'**

In my example the EventAttendee is added but their ResponseStatus is 'actionNeeded' - hence it is not visible in the calendar despite the owner being the user.

If in my code, I set the ResponseStatus of the EventAttendee to 'accepted' then it becomes visible in the users calendar.  Correct code needs to be:

```
        Event ev = new Event();
        ev.Summary = "ILINK TEST - IGNORE";
        ev.Start = new EventDateTime();
        ev.Start.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
        ev.End = new EventDateTime();
        ev.End.DateTime = ev.Start.DateTime;
        ev.Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
        EventAttendee ea = new EventAttendee();
        ea.Email = "example@example.com";
        ea.ResponseStatus = "accepted";
        ev.Attendees.Add(ea);
        Event evv = service.Events.Insert(ev, "example@example.com").Execute();
```